# Automate AWS Billing Report Generation and Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, automation, reporting

I am trying to see if there is a not-so-horrible way to have some AWS Billing Reports from the Cost Explorer (not the monthly bill) generated and distributed via e-mail to certain people. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the Cost Explorer API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no easy way through AWS directly, there are 3th party cloud cost management providers that enables that kind of automated reporting.

We have implemented Cost Explorer API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_AWS_Cost_Explorer_Service.html to get especially Forecast, Reservations Coverage and Utilization and a breakdown for underutilize instance and integrate this with our team Slack channel. This will enable cost-awareness for all team members.

Answer (score 0):

Getting cost reports to our emails has been simplified by an approach. We can make use of Cost-explorer API, Lambda, and SES to send emails using SES to certain people. You can find the architecture diagram here

[image]

We are using SES for getting a custom html template as an email output.
Create an Eventbridge schedule at the specific time of your interest for invocation with a Lambda as trigger.

Add the following code in the lambda with Python as runtime.Also add necessary permissions for the lambda role.

```
import json
import boto3
import datetime
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import pandas as pd
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     
    billing_client = boto3.client('ce')
    # getting dates (yyyy-MM-dd) and converting to string 
    today = datetime.date.today()
    yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days = 1) 
    str_today = str(today) 
    str_yesterday = str(yesterday)
     
    # get total cost for the previous day
    response_total = billing_client.get_cost_and_usage( 
       TimePeriod={ 
         'Start': str_esterday,
         'End': str_today,
         #'Start': "2023-05-16",
        # 'End': "2023-05-17"
         },
       Granularity='DAILY', 
       Metrics=[ 'UnblendedCost',] 
    )
     
    total_cost = response_total["ResultsByTime"][0]['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
    print(total_cost)
    total_cost=float(total_cost)
    total_cost=round(total_cost, 3)
    total_cost = '$' + str(total_cost)
     
    # print the total cost
    print('Total cost for yesterday: ' + total_cost)
     
    # get detailed billing for individual resources
    response_detail = billing_client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={
           'Start': str_yesterday,
           'End': str_today,
        },
        Granularity='DAILY',
        Metrics=['UnblendedCost'],
        GroupBy=[
            {
                'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                'Key': 'SERVICE'
            },
            {
                'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                'Key': 'USAGE_TYPE'
            }
        ]
    )
 
    resources = {'Service':[],'Usage Type':[],'Cost':[]}
     
    for result in response_detail['ResultsByTime'][0]['Groups']:
        group_key = result['Keys']
        service = group_key[0]
        usage_type = group_key[1]
        cost = result['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
        cost=float(cost)
        cost=round(cost, 3)
         
        if cost > 0:
            cost = '$' + str(cost)
            resources['Service'].append(service)
            resources['Usage Type'].append(usage_type)
            resources['Cost'].append(cost)
             
    df = pd.DataFrame(resources)
    html_table = df.to_html(index=False)
             
    print(resources)        
     
    message = 'Cost of AWS training account for yesterday was' 
     
    html = """
            <html>
              <head>
                <style>
                  body {{
                    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                    color: white;
                    background-color: black;
                  }}
                  h2 {{
                    color: white;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    text-align: center;
                  }}
                  h1 {{
                    color: #333333;
                    font-size: 40px;
                    text-align: center;
                    background-color: yellow;
                  }}
                  p {{
                    color: white;
                    font-size: 30px;
                    line-height: 1.5;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                    text-align: center;
                  }}
                  p1 {{
                     font-size: 10px;
                     text-align: center;
                      margin-left: auto;
                     margin-right: auto;
                  }}
                </style>
              </head>
              <body>
                <p> Training Account report for the day {} </p>
                <h2> {} </h2>
                <h1> <strong> <em> {} </em></strong> </h1>
                <p1>{}</p1>
              </body>
            </html>
            """.format(str_yesterday,message,total_cost,html_table)
             
 
     
    ses_client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1')
     
    message = {
        'Subject': {'Data': 'AWS training account cost report'},
        'Body': {'Html': {'Data': html}}
    }
     
    
    response = ses_client.send_email(
        Source="<SES_verified_identity>",
        Destination={'ToAddresses': [ "email-1","email-2"]},
        Message=message
    )
     
    if today.weekday() == 4:
        print('week')
        week = today - datetime.timedelta(days = 7) 
        str_week = str(week)
         
        response_total = billing_client.get_cost_and_usage( 
           TimePeriod={ 
             'Start': str_week, 
             'End': str_today }, 
           Granularity='MONTHLY', 
           Metrics=[ 'UnblendedCost',] 
        )
         
        print(response_total)
        length=len(response_total["ResultsByTime"])
        print(length)
         
        if (length==2):
            total_cost_1 = response_total["ResultsByTime"][0]['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
            total_cost_2 = response_total["ResultsByTime"][1]['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
            total_cost_1=float(total_cost_1)
            total_cost_2=float(total_cost_2)
            total_cost = total_cost_1+total_cost_2
            total_cost=round(total_cost, 3)
            total_cost = '$' + str(total_cost)
             
            # print the total cost
            print('Total cost for the week: ' + total_cost)
             
            # get detailed billing for individual resources
            response_detail = billing_client.get_cost_and_usage(
                TimePeriod={
                    'Start': str_week,
                    'End': str_today
                },
                Granularity='MONTHLY',
                Metrics=['UnblendedCost'],
                GroupBy=[
                    {
                        'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                        'Key': 'SERVICE'
                    },
                    {
                        'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                        'Key': 'USAGE_TYPE'
                    }
                ]
            )
             
            resources = {'Service':[],'Usage Type':[],'Cost':[]}
            resources_1 = {'Service':[],'Usage Type':[],'Cost':[]}
             
            for result in response_detail['ResultsByTime'][0]['Groups']:
                group_key = result['Keys']
                service = group_key[0]
                usage_type = group_key[1]
                cost = result['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
                cost=float(cost)
                cost=round(cost, 3)
                 
                if cost > 0:
                    cost = '$' + str(cost)
                    resources['Service'].append(service)
                    resources['Usage Type'].append(usage_type)
                    resources['Cost'].append(cost)
                     
            for result in response_detail['ResultsByTime'][1]['Groups']:
                group_key = result['Keys']
                service = group_key[0]
                usage_type = group_key[1]
                cost = result['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
                cost=float(cost)
                cost=round(cost, 3)
 
                if cost > 0:
                    cost = '$' + str(cost)
                    resources_1['Service'].append(service)
                    resources_1['Usage Type'].append(usage_type)
                    resources_1['Cost'].append(cost)
                     
            for key, value in resources_1.items():
                if key in resources:
                    resources[key] += value
                else:
                    resources[key] = value
        else:
            total_cost = response_total["ResultsByTime"][0]['Total']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
            total_cost=float(total_cost)
            total_cost=round(total_cost, 3)
            total_cost = '$' + str(total_cost)
             
            # print the total cost
            print('Total cost for the week: ' + total_cost)
             
            # get detailed billing for individual resources
            response_detail = billing_client.get_cost_and_usage(
                TimePeriod={
                    'Start': str_week,
                    'End': str_today
                },
                Granularity='MONTHLY',
                Metrics=['UnblendedCost'],
                GroupBy=[
                    {
                        'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                        'Key': 'SERVICE'
                    },
                    {
                        'Type': 'DIMENSION',
                        'Key': 'USAGE_TYPE'
                    }
                ]
            )
             
            resources = {'Service':[],'Usage Type':[],'Cost':[]}
             
            for result in response_detail['ResultsByTime'][0]['Groups']:
                group_key = result['Keys']
                service = group_key[0]
                usage_type = group_key[1]
                cost = result['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
                cost=float(cost)
                cost=round(cost, 3)
                 
                if cost > 0:
                    cost = '$' + str(cost)
                    resources['Service'].append(service)
                    resources['Usage Type'].append(usage_type)
                    resources['Cost'].append(cost)
                     
        print(type(resources))
                 
        df = pd.DataFrame(resources)
        html_table = df.to_html(index=False)
                 
        print(resources)        
         
        message = 'Cost of AWS training account for the  was' 
         
        html = """
                <html>
                  <head>
                    <style>
                      body {{
                        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                        color: white;
                        background-color: black;
                      }}
                      h2 {{
                        color: white;
                        font-size: 25px;
                        text-align: center;
                      }}
                      h1 {{
                        color: #333333;
                        font-size: 40px;
                        text-align: center;
                        background-color: yellow;
                      }}
                      p {{
                        color: white;
                        font-size: 30px;
                        line-height: 1.5;
                        margin-bottom: 20px;
                        text-align: center;
                      }}
                      p1 {{
                         font-size: 10px;
                         text-align: center;
                          margin-left: auto;
                         margin-right: auto;
                      }}
                    </style>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                    <p> Training Account report for the week {} and {} </p>
                    <h2> {} </h2>
                    <h1> <strong> <em> {} </em></strong> </h1>
                    <p1>{}</p1>
                  </body>
                </html>
                """.format(str_week,str_today,message,total_cost,html_table)
                      
        ses_client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-east-1')
         
        message = {
            'Subject': {'Data': 'AWS training account cost report'},
            'Body': {'Html': {'Data': html}}
        }
         
        response = ses_client.send_email(
            Source='<SES-verified-identity>',
            Destination={'ToAddresses': [ 'email-1','email-2']},
            Message=message
        )
         
        print(response)
```

You can find solution in the links below - The solution proposed sends daily and weekly reports.

https://medium.com/@TechStoryLines/generate-aws-cost-reports-automatically-using-the-cost-explorer-api-ef472fca4151

https://techstorylines.hashnode.dev/generate-aws-cost-reports-automatically-using-the-cost-explorer-api